# utf 8 encoding not working

Tags: encoding, utf-8

i have an utf8 encoding issue.
i have  on all my html sites. 
but if you go to http://lukasrauen.com/about.html you can see that some letters like ü or – are displayed wrong.

sometimes it works, sometimes it doesnt. but if you change the page to work and change it back to about it displays wrong.

what could be the fault for that?

i changed the serversettings to default_charset utf8, but still it doesnt work. 
I implemented history.js for fluid page transitions, maybe it has something to do with that?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the file is actually saved in UTF-8 format.

Comment: thanks, saved it in textedit again in utf-8 now it works

Answer (score 1):

Your page says it is UTF-8 but really it isn't. Enter the URL of your website at the [W3C Validator](https://validator.w3.org/) to see for yourself.

This is the current result for http://lukasrauen.com/about.html

[image: W3C Validation results]